# Testing for mutual exclusivity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, expected-value, t-distribution

So first, sorry if I use non-standard vocabulary, since I am not an expert. Please feel free to correct.

I would like to know if a set of genes in a patient cohort are mutated by a mutually exclusive manner. While one can observe this easily by eye, it is unclear to me how to test this in a statistical rigorous way for a gene set more than two genes. All the patients suffer the same disease)

The scenario is this: 4 genes (g1, ..., g4), 15 patients (p1, ..., p15). If a gene is mutated in a patient, its denoted as 1, otherwise 0 for no observation.

```
\  | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | p6 | p7 | p8 | p9 | p10|
-----------------------------------------------------
g1 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
g2 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |
g3 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  |
g4 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |
```

While it may be obvious to the observer that this group of genes are mutated in a mutually exclusive manner.

- *How would I test if this distribution of events has not happened by chance*? The underlying hypothesis is, that there is a selective pressure on that any of the four genes must have a mutation to in order to have the disease.

Could it be done by Chi Square testing?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you explain what exactly constitutes 'mutually exclusive mutation' in the table? Is it than there's no more than a single '1' in a column? Exactly one '1' in each column? Some other criterion? Is it actually a logical notion or a probabilistic one?

Comment: I take you to mean by mutually exclusive that each person has a mutation in one gene and none of the other 3.  What are you trying to assess significance of, exactly?  The significance of finding this cohort of people?  The number of people with a mutation of a given gene?

Comment: **GlenB**: yes, it is a binary information - mutation observed, yes/no. **learner**: you are right. I want to know if this observation could also be observed by chance. So if it only were two genes I would perform a Fisher´s test.

Comment: I have added some more detail to the original question. I hope it makes things clearer

Comment: @dmeu your response there was almost completely unhelpful. I already understood the data to be binary, indicating presence or absence of a mutation. My questions related to the way you were defining *mutually exclusive* in respect of that table. Please address the specific questions in my original comment.

Comment: @Glen_b : It is a logic notion (please note that I had added some more description in the question itself that explains a bit this point). Each column should only have one 1, which leads to mutually exclusion between the rows.

Comment: Then each set of results is either mutually exclusive or it isn't. Right now, I don't see any way to generate a sampling distribution for it.

Comment: Well the example given above is a best-case example - there _may_ be the case that a column as more than one 1 and still, I would call it mutually exclusive. But my issue exaclty is, that I don't have any means to call it mutually exclusive by means of statistics.

Comment: I don't think you'll get one. You're in search of a criterion, and I don't see how that relates to what statistics does. Your problem isn't clearly related to statistics at all.

Comment: @Glen_b What is it related to, then if not statistics? I am sorry, but I really do not know. With two items I could easily make a fishers t-test to asses the distribution. I just do not see how to do it for three and more

Comment: If you had some kind of probability model in there, we could talk about statistics. You just have a rule that says 'mutually exclusive' or 'not'. It's like having a collection of balls and saying "I can detect if all the balls in my collection are red, and say 'all red'..." -- that's all very well, but without something more than that, we have no basis for figuring out the probabilities connected to how *else* it might have turned out